# Why can´t I get the text in a \framebox stick to the bottom?

Tags: latex3

When using a \fbox combined with a tabular I can create a box of almost the size I defined and get the text to stick to the bottom of the box.

However, when I try doing the same thing with a \framebox where I can specify the exact sizes of the box, the text is always at the top.
Also the text to the left of the box will never be centered in the middle of the box only at the bottom.

In summary: I want the result in the top of my example 1 (with Text1 and Stamp1) but with the exact dimensions of the box from example 2 (With Text2 and Stamp2).

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{1cm}r}
Text1
 &&
\fbox{
    \begin{tabular}{p{6cm}}
    \vspace{1,8cm}
    \centering{\tiny{Stamp1}}
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{lp{1cm}r}
Text2
 & 
\framebox(6cm, 2.5cm){
\vspace{1,8cm}
\centering{\tiny Stamp2}}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use a `\parbox` with specified vertical dimension and inner alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Text 1\qquad
\fbox{%
  \parbox[c][2.5cm][t]{6cm}{
    \centering\tiny
    \vspace*{2mm}% adjust to suit
    Stamp1
  }%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That works. However, what I really wanted was the result you get with your solution and something like 22mm so that the text sits at the bottom...

Comment: @mrCarnivore Sorry, but I don't get it. If you want “Stamp1” at the bottom, change `[t]` into `[b]` and swap the text and `\vspace*`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks. Actually you can even omit the ```\vspace*``` then and it still works.